# Setting up a Border Style template but allowing flexibility for values used

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this `Border` style:

```
<Border.Style>
    <Style x:Uid="Style_36" TargetType="Border">
        <Setter x:Uid="Setter_94" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger x:Uid="DataTrigger_36" Binding="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=comboActiveStudentAssignmentType}" 
                         Value="{x:Static StudentInfoEnums:StudentAssignmentType.Student1Main}">
                <Setter x:Uid="Setter_95" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Border.Style>
```

I know how to place a style into the `Window.Resources` and then apply it to any control. But I need to tweak each instance. In the text:

> ```
> <Border.Style>
>     <Style x:Uid="Style_36" TargetType="Border">
>         <Setter x:Uid="Setter_94" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
>         <Style.Triggers>
>             <DataTrigger x:Uid="DataTrigger_36" Binding="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=comboActiveStudentAssignmentType}" 
>                          Value="{x:Static StudentInfoEnums:StudentAssignmentType.Student1Main}">
>                 <Setter x:Uid="Setter_95" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
>             </DataTrigger>
>         </Style.Triggers>
>     </Style>
> </Border.Style>
> ```

This bit:

> Value="{x:Static StudentInfoEnums:StudentAssignmentType.**Student1Main**}">

needs to change for each `Border` on the window. So, how can I set up a style to simplify my code but allow this property to change?

Possible?

### Update

Since each border should only diaplay when the combo is a certain value, and the suggestion was to put all the data triggers into the style template, I began by trying:

```
<Style x:Uid="Style_38" x:Key="StudentAssignmentFocusedBorder" TargetType="Border">
    <Setter x:Uid="Setter_94" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger x:Uid="MultiDataTrigger_5">
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition x:Uid="Condition_11" Binding="{Binding SelectedtItem, ElementName=comboActiveStudentAssignmentType}" Value="{x:Static StudentInfoEnums:StudentAssignmentType.Student1Main}"/>
                <Condition x:Uid="Condition_12" Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="borderMainHallStudent1"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter x:Uid="Setter_95" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

But that doesn't work.

Comment: you can write a DataTrigger for each enum value in the same style

Comment: @ASh I think I get you. I will give that a try. Thanks.

Comment: @ASh I don't think I can do this. I have 12 places where I have a border. I only want the border to display if the combo choice is XYZ. If I add all of the triggers into the style list the rectangle will show for all of them because atleast one of the triggers would match. Perhaps, if we could do: "if border name is XYZ and combo item is ABC " and have them in a list we could do it.

Comment: It would be possible by overriding Border and adding a dependency property you can bind to. I'm curious to see if someone comes up with an easier solution.

Comment: To be honest, in this particular case, i'd use a `Behavior`. Its less stressy, to implement that logic in some kind of code behind than spending ages of thinking about how this could be done in plain XAML. Overriding a control for a simple visual effect is bit overkill imo...

Comment: @lokusking I have not used behaviours. Could you please show me? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This **NOT** beautiful but enhancing your possibilities, since you can bind your `StudentInfoEnums:StudentAssignmentType.Student1Main`-Enum.

Some random demo-**XAML** to Test:

```
<Window x:Class="SelectButtonSample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SelectButtonSample"

        mc:Ignorable="d"        
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        Title="MainWindow" >
    <Grid Height="200">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Click me" Width="80" Height="20" >
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <local:MyBorderBehavior MyEnumPropery="Two"/>
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </Button>
            <CheckBox Content="Click me" x:Name="chk">
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <local:MyBorderBehavior MyEnumPropery="Three"/>
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </CheckBox>
            <ListView>
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <local:MyBorderBehavior MyEnumPropery="One"></local:MyBorderBehavior>
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
              <ListViewItem Content="Item1">
                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <local:MyBorderBehavior MyEnumPropery="Four"></local:MyBorderBehavior>
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Item 2</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Item 3</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Item 4</ListViewItem>
            </ListView>

        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My Demo-Enum:

```
public enum MyEnum
    {
        One,
        Two,
        Three,
        Four

    }
```

The **Magic**:

```
public class MyBorderBehavior : Behavior<Control>
    {
        public MyEnum MyEnumPropery {
            get { return (MyEnum) GetValue(MyEnumProperyProperty); }
            set { SetValue(MyEnumProperyProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MyEnumProperyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyEnumPropery", typeof(MyEnum), typeof(MyBorderBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(PropertyChangedCallback));

        private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dO, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
        {
            var self = dO as MyBorderBehavior;
            if (self != null && self._controlToColorBorder != null)
                self.SetColor();
        }

        private Control _controlToColorBorder;

        private void SetColor()
        {
            switch (this.MyEnumPropery)
            {
                case MyEnum.One:
                    this._controlToColorBorder.BorderBrush = Brushes.Yellow;
                    break;
                case MyEnum.Two:
                    this._controlToColorBorder.BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;
                    break;
                case MyEnum.Three:
                    this._controlToColorBorder.BorderBrush = Brushes.Green;
                    break;
                case MyEnum.Four:
                    this._controlToColorBorder.BorderBrush = Brushes.DeepPink;
                    break;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            this._controlToColorBorder = this.AssociatedObject;
            this._controlToColorBorder.Loaded += ControlToColorBorderLoaded;
            base.OnAttached();
        }

        private void ControlToColorBorderLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.SetColor();
        }
    }
```

**Notes:**

- As you can see, you have to use the
  `System.Windows.Interactivity`-Assembly
- This little `Behavior` can applied to everything of type `Control`
  (Since Control has `BorderBrush`-Property)
- I've implemented a `DependencyProperty` to make things bindable.
- Four your purpose, you sure have to replace `MyEnum` with yours and
  adjust the colors. Furthermore, you might have to implement another
  `DependencyProperty` to bring your 2nd condition to the Behavior.

Hope this gives you a clue, on how you can get ahead with your code.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look. I will have to work out how to bring in the second property as I think it will be needed. Will update you in due course.