# Setting focus rectangle to red / transparent and ensuring visible

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a related question with a proposed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38480443/setting-up-a-border-style-template-but-allowing-flexibility-for-values-used/38486032#38486032) but my issue is more complex and I think it is best to start a new question. I hope that is OK.

I think it is important to visually show you what I am trying to do first. Here is an overview of the editor:

[image: Overview of the editor]

Down the left are several controls that are used to display the chosen students (and assistants where applicable). The editor supports 3 classes for the students. Thus, I have the students for each class on a `TabItem` control.

Example:

[image: Sample section]

As you can see, it has a `TabControl` with 3 items (Main Hall, Class 1 and Class 2). On each of those tab items they then have their own TabControl with the 3 student items.

You see those small icons next to the text boxes? If you click those then they affect a combo that is over on the right side of the editor:

[image: Assignments]

So when you click a small icon, it automatically selects the right entry in the combo on the right. Then, as you select a student from the grid it gets populated into the right part of the editor:

[image: Selecting a student]

### The Issue

When the user manually changes the combo over on the right, it then needs to set a focus rectangle over on th left hand side correctly. So when a item is selected it needs to:

1. Set the tab item as selected (if needed).
2. Set the border brush of the rectangle to red instead of transparent.

I have got it to set the rectangle colours as required but I have not yet managed to do that using behaviours (as per the related question). In addition, when I try fiddling with the `IsSelected` property of the 'TabItem' objects I find that they sometimes kind of collapse on screen. I have commented out my code.

I am sorry for the wordier question but I will get asked for clarification so I am trying to cover it up front.

So:

There are two main `TabControl` objects:

The first is the bible reading items:

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <TabItem x:Name="tabTFGWReadingMainHall" Header="Main Hall" DataContext="{Binding Meeting}">
        <TabItem.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                <!--<Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>-->
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NumberClasses, ConverterParameter=1, Converter={StaticResource IsEqualOrGreaterThanConverter}}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <!--<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=comboActiveStudentAssignmentType}" Value="{x:Static StudentInfoEnums:StudentAssignmentType.BibleReadingMain}">
                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                    </DataTrigger>-->
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TabItem.Style>
        <Border x:Name="borderBibleReadingMain" BorderThickness="5">
            <Border.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=comboActiveStudentAssignmentType}" Value="{x:Static StudentInfoEnums:StudentAssignmentType.BibleReadingMain}">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NumberClasses, ConverterParameter=1, Converter={StaticResource IsEqualOrGreaterThanConverter}}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </StackPanel.Style>
                <Label Content="Student:"/>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBox x:Name="textBibleReadingMain" Grid.Column="0" Margin="2" IsEnabled="False"
                        Text="{Binding BibleReadingMainName, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    <Button x:Name="buttonBibleReadingMain" Grid.Column="1" Background="Transparent"
                        DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=oclmEditor}"
                            Command="{Binding ApplicationCommand}" CommandParameter="BibleReadingMain">
                        <Image Source="Images/AssignmentTypeBibleReading16.png" Margin="2"/>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
                <Label Content="Study:"/>

                <ComboBox DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=oclmEditor}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding ReadingStudyPointsList}"
                      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource StudyPointComboBoxStyle}"
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StudyPointComboItem}"
                      Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource StudyPointValidationTemplate}"
                      Tag="{Binding Meeting.BibleReadingMainName, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      SelectedValue="{Binding Meeting.BibleReadingMainStudyPoint, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      SelectedValuePath="Number">
                    <!--<ComboBox.Style>
                    <Style 
                        TargetType="ComboBox" 
                        BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                                <Setter 
                                    Property="ToolTip"
                                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ComboBox.Style>
                <ComboBox.SelectedValue>
                    <Binding Path="Meeting.BibleReadingMainStudyPoint"
                         Mode="TwoWay"
                         UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
                         NotifyOnValidationError="True">
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <ValidationRules:StudyPointValidationRule BibleReading="True"/>
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </ComboBox.SelectedValue>-->
                </ComboBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem x:Name="tabTFGWReadingClass1" Header="Class 1" DataContext="{Binding Meeting}">
        <TabItem.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NumberClasses, ConverterParameter=2, Converter={StaticResource IsEqualOrGreaterThanConverter}}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=comboActiveStudentAssignmentType}" Value="{x:Static StudentInfoEnums:StudentAssignmentType.BibleReadingClass1}">
                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TabItem.Style>
        <Border x:Name="borderBibleReadingClass1" BorderThickness="5">
            <Border.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=comboActiveStudentAssignmentType}" Value="{x:Static StudentInfoEnums:StudentAssignmentType.BibleReadingClass1}">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NumberClasses, ConverterParameter=2, Converter={StaticResource IsEqualOrGreaterThanConverter}}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </StackPanel.Style>
                <Label Content="Student:"/>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBox x:Name="textBibleReadingClass1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="2" IsEnabled="False"
                    Text="{Binding BibleReadingClass1Name, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    <Button x:Name="buttonBibleReadingClass1" Grid.Column="1" Background="Transparent"
                    DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=oclmEditor}"
                        Command="{Binding ApplicationCommand}" CommandParameter="BibleReadingClass1">
                        <Image Source="Images/AssignmentTypeBibleReading16.png" Margin="2"/>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
                <Label Content="Study:"/>
                <ComboBox DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=oclmEditor}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding ReadingStudyPointsList}"
                      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource StudyPointComboBoxStyle}"
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StudyPointComboItem}"
                      Tag="{Binding Meeting.BibleReadingClass1Name, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      SelectedValue="{Binding Meeting.BibleReadingClass1StudyPoint, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      SelectedValuePath="Number"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem x:Name="tabTFGWReadingClass2" Header="Class 2" DataContext="{Binding Meeting}">
        <TabItem.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NumberClasses, ConverterParameter=3, Converter={StaticResource IsEqualOrGreaterThanConverter}}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=comboActiveStudentAssignmentType}" Value="{x:Static StudentInfoEnums:StudentAssignmentType.BibleReadingClass2}">
                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TabItem.Style>
        <Border x:Name="borderBibleReadingClass2" BorderThickness="5">
            <Border.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=comboActiveStudentAssignmentType}" Value="{x:Static StudentInfoEnums:StudentAssignmentType.BibleReadingClass2}">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Border.Style>
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding NumberClasses, ConverterParameter=3, Converter={StaticResource IsEqualOrGreaterThanConverter}}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </StackPanel.Style>
                <Label Content="Student:"/>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBox x:Name="textBibleReadingClass2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="2" IsEnabled="False"
                Text="{Binding BibleReadingClass2Name, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                    <Button x:Name="buttonBibleReadingClass2" Grid.Column="1" Background="Transparent"
                DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=oclmEditor}"
                    Command="{Binding ApplicationCommand}" CommandParameter="BibleReadingClass2">
                        <Image Source="Images/AssignmentTypeBibleReading16.png" Margin="2"/>
                    </Button>
                </Grid>
                <Label Content="Study:"/>
                <ComboBox DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=oclmEditor}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding ReadingStudyPointsList}"
                      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource StudyPointComboBoxStyle}"
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StudyPointComboItem}"
                      Tag="{Binding Meeting.BibleReadingClass2Name, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      SelectedValue="{Binding Meeting.BibleReadingClass2StudyPoint, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      SelectedValuePath="Number"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

The second is the `tabControlAYFMStudents` control but I have to keep my question body limited. So I have not shown it.

I don't expect anyone to read through all my code. So if you think I should remove this question then please advise me so. Or if you think I can ask it somewhere else.

I would just like to be able to get the rectangle border set as transparent (or red) based on the current combo item selected. And, ensure it is visible.

Phew! Thank you.

Comment: Ya this one is going to be quite a bit too broad for my spare time allowance. So I went ahead and del'd my answer. Sorry amigo, will swing back if I can find more free time. I'd probably steer you in some other directions that would require a significant refactoring of how you're doing stuff currently that would require a good amount more involvement than what SO is generally a platform to use for.

Comment: @ChrisW.That is OK. I understand. This is essentially my first WPF project so it has been a steep learning curve. Thanks again.

Comment: @ChrisW. I did a code behind. Works very well. It has one issue (as mentioned at bottom of the answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided during the night that using the code behind would be the simplest solution for my issues. I added a handler for the `SelectionChanged` event:

```
private void comboActiveStudentAssignmentType_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    List<Border> borders = new List<Border>();

    // The list of border (focus rectangles) matches the combo of assignment types
    borders.Add(borderBibleReadingMain);
    borders.Add(borderBibleReadingClass1);
    borders.Add(borderBibleReadingClass2);
    borders.Add(borderMainHallStudent1);
    borders.Add(borderMainHallAssistant1);
    borders.Add(borderMainHallStudent2);
    borders.Add(borderMainHallAssistant2);
    borders.Add(borderMainHallStudent3);
    borders.Add(borderMainHallAssistant3);
    borders.Add(borderClass1Student1);
    borders.Add(borderClass1Assistant1);
    borders.Add(borderClass1Student2);
    borders.Add(borderClass1Assistant2);
    borders.Add(borderClass1Student3);
    borders.Add(borderClass1Assistant3);
    borders.Add(borderClass2Student1);
    borders.Add(borderClass2Assistant1);
    borders.Add(borderClass2Student2);
    borders.Add(borderClass2Assistant2);
    borders.Add(borderClass2Student3);
    borders.Add(borderClass2Assistant3);

    // Loop through the borders
    for(int iBorder = 0; iBorder < borders.Count; iBorder++)
    {
        // Is this border the active student assignment?
        if (comboActiveStudentAssignmentType.SelectedIndex == iBorder)
        {
            // Yes, so use a red brush for the background
            borders[iBorder].BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;

            // Now we must ensure the correct tab item is visible
            if(iBorder >= 0 && iBorder <= 2)
            {
                expandTFGW.IsExpanded = true;

                if (iBorder == 0)
                    tabTFGWReadingMainHall.IsSelected = true;
                else if (iBorder == 1)
                    tabTFGWReadingClass1.IsSelected = true;
                else if (iBorder == 2)
                    tabTFGWReadingClass2.IsSelected = true;
            }
            else if (iBorder >= 3 && iBorder <= 8)
            {
                expandAYFM.IsExpanded = true;
                tabAYFMStudentsMainHall.IsSelected = true;

                if (iBorder == 3 || iBorder == 4)
                    tabMainHallItem1.IsSelected = true;
                else if (iBorder == 5 || iBorder == 6)
                    tabMainHallItem2.IsSelected = true;
                else if (iBorder == 7 || iBorder == 8)
                    tabMainHallItem3.IsSelected = true;
            }
            else if (iBorder >= 9 && iBorder <= 14)
            {
                expandAYFM.IsExpanded = true;
                tabAYFMStudentsClass1.IsSelected = true;

                if (iBorder == 9 || iBorder == 10)
                    tabClass1Item1.IsSelected = true;
                else if (iBorder == 11 || iBorder == 12)
                    tabClass1Item2.IsSelected = true;
                else if (iBorder == 13 || iBorder == 14)
                    tabClass1Item3.IsSelected = true;
            }
            else if (iBorder >= 15)
            {
                expandAYFM.IsExpanded = true;
                tabAYFMStudentsClass2.IsSelected = true;

                if (iBorder == 15 || iBorder == 16)
                    tabClass2Item1.IsSelected = true;
                else if (iBorder == 17 || iBorder == 18)
                    tabClass2Item2.IsSelected = true;
                else if (iBorder == 19 || iBorder == 20)
                    tabClass2Item3.IsSelected = true;
            }

            borders[iBorder].BringIntoView();
        }
        else
        {
            // No, so set the background to transparent so we can't see it.
            borders[iBorder].BorderBrush = Brushes.Transparent;
        }
    }
}
```

}

This works fine. As you change the combo the correct `Border` is set to red and it's associated `TabItem` is set to `Selected`.

In addition, I set the associated `Expander` to expanded. This means I am 95% where I want to be. I can remove all of the DataTriggers from the XAML as it is all now managed in this one handler.

However, this call doesn't seem to work:

```
borders[iBorder].BringIntoView();
```

So even though the above will set the border properties and ensure it's tab item is selected, I can't ensure the control is visible if it is off-screen.

### Update

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38532196/bringintoview-is-not-working/38532493?noredirect=1#comment64459593_38532493) explains how tobring the rectangle into view:

```
var localBorderIndex = iBorder; // copy to avoid closure of loop variable
Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => borders[localBorderIndex].BringIntoView(),
    DispatcherPriority.Background);
```