# BringIntoView is not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, code-behind

I have this code behind event handler:

```
private void comboActiveStudentAssignmentType_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    List<Border> borders = new List<Border>();

    // The list of border (focus rectangles) matches the combo of assignment types
    borders.Add(borderBibleReadingMain);
    borders.Add(borderBibleReadingClass1);
    borders.Add(borderBibleReadingClass2);
    borders.Add(borderMainHallStudent1);
    borders.Add(borderMainHallAssistant1);
    borders.Add(borderMainHallStudent2);
    borders.Add(borderMainHallAssistant2);
    borders.Add(borderMainHallStudent3);
    borders.Add(borderMainHallAssistant3);
    borders.Add(borderClass1Student1);
    borders.Add(borderClass1Assistant1);
    borders.Add(borderClass1Student2);
    borders.Add(borderClass1Assistant2);
    borders.Add(borderClass1Student3);
    borders.Add(borderClass1Assistant3);
    borders.Add(borderClass2Student1);
    borders.Add(borderClass2Assistant1);
    borders.Add(borderClass2Student2);
    borders.Add(borderClass2Assistant2);
    borders.Add(borderClass2Student3);
    borders.Add(borderClass2Assistant3);

    // Loop through the borders
    for(int iBorder = 0; iBorder < borders.Count; iBorder++)
    {
        // Is this border the active student assignment?
        if (comboActiveStudentAssignmentType.SelectedIndex == iBorder)
        {
            // Yes, so use a red brush for the background
            borders[iBorder].BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;

            // Now we must ensure the correct tab item is visible
            if(iBorder >= 0 && iBorder <= 2)
            {
                expandTFGW.IsExpanded = true;

                if (iBorder == 0)
                    tabTFGWReadingMainHall.IsSelected = true;
                else if (iBorder == 1)
                    tabTFGWReadingClass1.IsSelected = true;
                else if (iBorder == 2)
                    tabTFGWReadingClass2.IsSelected = true;
            }
            else if (iBorder >= 3 && iBorder <= 8)
            {
                expandAYFM.IsExpanded = true;
                tabAYFMStudentsMainHall.IsSelected = true;

                if (iBorder == 3 || iBorder == 4)
                    tabMainHallItem1.IsSelected = true;
                else if (iBorder == 5 || iBorder == 6)
                    tabMainHallItem2.IsSelected = true;
                else if (iBorder == 7 || iBorder == 8)
                    tabMainHallItem3.IsSelected = true;
            }
            else if (iBorder >= 9 && iBorder <= 14)
            {
                expandAYFM.IsExpanded = true;
                tabAYFMStudentsClass1.IsSelected = true;

                if (iBorder == 9 || iBorder == 10)
                    tabClass1Item1.IsSelected = true;
                else if (iBorder == 11 || iBorder == 12)
                    tabClass1Item2.IsSelected = true;
                else if (iBorder == 13 || iBorder == 14)
                    tabClass1Item3.IsSelected = true;
            }
            else if (iBorder >= 15)
            {
                expandAYFM.IsExpanded = true;
                tabAYFMStudentsClass2.IsSelected = true;

                if (iBorder == 15 || iBorder == 16)
                    tabClass2Item1.IsSelected = true;
                else if (iBorder == 17 || iBorder == 18)
                    tabClass2Item2.IsSelected = true;
                else if (iBorder == 19 || iBorder == 20)
                    tabClass2Item3.IsSelected = true;
            }

            borders[iBorder].BringIntoView();
        }
        else
        {
            // No, so set the background to transparent so we can't see it.
            borders[iBorder].BorderBrush = Brushes.Transparent;
        }
    }
}
```

}

An example of one of the `Border` objects in XAML:

```
<Border x:Uid="borderMainHallStudent1" x:Name="borderMainHallStudent1" BorderThickness="5">
    <Border.Style>
        <Style x:Uid="Style_30" TargetType="Border">
            <Setter x:Uid="Setter_76" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger x:Uid="DataTrigger_29" Binding="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=comboActiveStudentAssignmentType}" 
                         Value="{x:Static StudentInfoEnums:StudentAssignmentType.Student1Main}">
                    <Setter x:Uid="Setter_77" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
    <StackPanel x:Uid="StackPanel_35">
        <Label x:Uid="Label_38" Content="Student:"/>
        <Grid x:Uid="Grid_15">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition x:Uid="ColumnDefinition_34" Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition x:Uid="ColumnDefinition_35" Width="auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox x:Uid="textMainHallStudent1" x:Name="textMainHallStudent1" 
                 Text="{Binding MainHallStudent1, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                 IsEnabled="False" Grid.Column="0" Margin="2" />
            <Button x:Uid="buttonMainHallStudent1" x:Name="buttonMainHallStudent1" Grid.Column="1" Background="Transparent"
                DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=oclmEditor}"
                Command="{Binding ApplicationCommand}"
                CommandParameter="Student1Main">
                <Image x:Uid="Image_17" Source="Images/AssignmentTypeStudent16.png" Margin="2"/>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
        <Label x:Uid="Label_39" Content="Study:"/>
        <ComboBox x:Uid="ComboBox_9" DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=oclmEditor}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding StudentStudyPointsList}" 
              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource StudyPointComboBoxStyle}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StudyPointComboItem}"
              Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource StudyPointValidationTemplate}"
              Tag="{Binding Meeting.MainHallStudent1, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              SelectedValue="{Binding Meeting.MainHallStudent1StudyNumber, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
              SelectedValuePath="Number"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

This line of code: `borders[iBorder].BringIntoView();` It does not seem to work. The colours of all my Border objects is set correctly, but the program evidently makes no attempt to object this line of code.

To give you the context of where this `Border` object exists:

```
\\ Main Window
    \\ScrollView
       \\ Expander
          \\Tab Control
             \\Tab Item
                 \\Border 1
                    \\Contents
                 \\Border 2
                     \\Contents
       \\ Expander
          \\Tab Control
             \\Tab Item
                 \\Border 1
                    \\Contents
                 \\Border 2
                     \\Contents
```

Comment: @EliArbel I am using data binding collections. This is shown in the XAML snippet. Still learning though. This specific code behind is just for the UI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`BringIntoView()`, according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.bringintoview(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Attempts to bring this element into view, within any **scrollable** regions it is contained within.

Therefore it will not select tab items, expand expanders, etc. You need to do that yourself.

Note that due to the dispatcher's priority queue, the content may not be available as soon as you make changes (such as select a tab). In that case, you may want to post the bring-into-view request in a lower priority:

```
var localBorderIndex = iBorder; // copy to avoid closure of loop variable
Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => borders[localBorderIndex].BringIntoView(),
    DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

Comment: I forgot to include the `ScrollView` in the context. I do have one. Should I be using `BringIntoView` on the relevant `Expander` instead as they are immediate children of the `ScrollView`? I thought the command would roll up the visual tree to the find my `ScrollView` you see. And, if you look at my code behind I do already expand the expanders and set the tabs **before** doing the `BringIntoView` call.

Comment: Thank you. Now it works fine. But perhaps you can have a discussion with me somehow about your comment re-repetative code. I am using data binding but if I can make more use of it and simplyfy my XAML and / or code I would like to learn this.

Comment: I understand. There are two related questions that might explain that for you, rather than me starting a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38505512/setting-focus-rectangle-to-red-transparent-and-ensuring-visible/38522056#38522056